# docker-compose not recognizing env_file file/location, and still tries to use the default .env

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Here's my compose file `dev.yml`

```
version: '2'

volumes:
  rethinkdb_data_dev: {}

services:
  rethinkdb:
    image: rethinkdb:latest
    volumes:
      - rethinkdb_data_dev:/home/rethinkdb_data

  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:latest

  fumio:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/fumio_dev/Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - rethinkdb
      - rabbitmq
    links:
      - rethinkdb
      - rabbitmq
    env_file: ./compose/fumio_dev/dev.env
    environment:
      - GIRLFRIEND_FUMIO_CONFIG=development
      - GIRLFRIEND_FUMIO_NOSQLDATABASE_HOST=rethinkdb
    ports:
      - "${GIRLFRIEND_FUMIO_PORT}:8001"
```

The `environment` inside the `dev.yml` file is intentional, so I can override them inside with `dev.env` if needed.

My `dev.env` file, located inside `compose/fumio_dev/` folder, relative to the `dev.yml` file.

```
GIRLFRIEND_FUMIO_PORT=8000
```

Here's what happens when I run `docker-compose -f dev.yml build`

[image]

If I provide `.env` file in the root folder, it runs fine, docker-compose ignores the `env_file`'s value and try to use the default `.env` instead. So docker-compose env_file is somehow not working as intended or I'm missing something?

My docker-compose version is 1.8.0, I downgraded it to 1.7.1 but still no luck (installed using pip).

Comment: I wasn't able to recreate your issue with a [simple example](https://gist.github.com/bmitch3020/2db1ec35e47c0ac4017ef9a5a0ddbf82).

Comment: Turns out `env_file` and default `.env` are different concepts -_-

Comment: I just now noticed your `ports` line, completely missed that you were trying to update the env inside of the yml rather than inside of the container.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The `.env` file in the project root, and the `env_file:` field in the Compose file are two different concepts.

The `.env` is for settings a default environment for **Compose**. Values set in this file can be used within the Compose file.

The `env_file:` field is for setting the default environment for a **container**. Values set in this can be used in the container, but not in the Compose file.

See https://docs.docker.com/compose/env-file/ for more information.

Comment: Yeah I read that link already, but in the `env_file` documentation, there is no mention if `env_file` can be used in `compose` or not, so I assume it can.

Comment: That explaines a lot of things. Wasted a significant amount of time with that nuance.... thanks.

Comment: For me it was not reading default .env file and I had to explicitly add it with env_file

Answer (score 5):

As @dnephin has explained,

> The env_file: field is for setting the default environment for a container. Values set in this can be used in the container, but not in the Compose file.

And one more thing I'd like to notice is that the `--env-file` flag that you can specify when executing the command, e.g. `docker-compose --env-file ./somefile`, and the `env_file` option in the compose file are absolutely different, too.

The `--env-file` flag enables you to determine a custom environment file that can be used in your Compose file.

So in your case, I think this command will do the trick:

`docker-compose --env-file ./compose/fumio_dev/dev.env -f dev.yml build`